# How can i show the value of all my for loops in one line

Tags: javascript, for-loop

so there's not really a problem but i just wanted to make this code better by displaying all the values of my for loop in one line.
JavaScript:

```
btn3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const number = document.querySelector('.input3').value
    const result3 = document.querySelector('.result3')
    let isPrime = true
    result3.innerHTML = ""
    for (let i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if (number % i === 0) {
            isPrime = false
            result3.innerHTML += `${number} is not prime<br/>
            ${number} can be divided by ${i}<br/>`
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        result3.innerHTML = `${number} is prime`
    }
})
```

For example if i write 6 i want it to display '6 is not prime it can be divided by 2,3'
Any ideas ??

Comment: Have the loop build an array of the numbers you want to display, then do the display after the loop.

Comment: You can check if the array is empty for prime.

Comment: Questions about how to improve working code are better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. before asking however go through their help section and make sure your question meets all their requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can collect all the numbers and then append it to the response... like so...

```
n=[]
btn3.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const number = document.querySelector('.input3').value
    const result3 = document.querySelector('.result3')
    let isPrime = true
    result3.innerHTML = ""
    for (let i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if (number % i === 0) {
            isPrime = false
            n+=${i}+","
        }
    }
    if (isPrime) {
        result3.innerHTML = `${number} is prime`
    } else {
        n=n.replace(/,$/,"")
        result3.innerHTML += `${number} is not prime<br/>${number} can be divided by`+n+`<br/>`
    }
})
```

Comment: yeah it works ! thank you so much ! there's some errors just like the backstics before calling the variable i or setting n = '' before so it won't append the array but nevermind it works great !